# Show value of data attribute on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to chained select controllers, where users can select exposure and then click packages depending on which exposure type they've selected. My problem is showing the price of these packages.

Currently I am trying to do it like this:

```
<select id='mark' name='mark'>
    <option value=''>--</option>
    <option value='micro'>Micro Exposure</option>
    <option value='mini'>Mini Exposure</option>
</select>
<select id='clicks' name='series'>
    <option value=''>--</option>
    <option value='clicks-2500' class='micro' data-price='4'>2500 Clicks</option>
    <option value='clicks-5000' class='micro' data-price='7'>5000 Clicks</option>
    <option value='clicks-10000' class='micro' data-price='13'>10000 Clicks</option>
    <option value='clicks-500' class='mini' data-price='4'>500 Clicks</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.micro').change(function() {
            $('#amountDiv').text($(this).data('price'));
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.mini').change(function() {
            $('#amountDiv').text($(this).data('price'));
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='amountDiv'></div>
```

As you can see, I'm storing the price of the packages with the HTML5 data attribute, but I cannot get it to show in `#amountDiv`

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Where is the data attribute "pricepack"? I only see price.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote incorrectly. I've updated my question with "price" now. (Didn't solve my problem though)

Comment: Much easier to read without all that spaces and empty lines ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use onchange event of select,:

```
$('#clicks').change(function () {
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JH7MA/

Comment: Oh, of course. Edited my question. But, it still doesn't work. Nothing happens on change..

Comment: Ya, because option doesn't have an onchange event, select got

Comment: Oh. How is it then possible to show the data attribute onchange?